# What is the Fedora equivalent to the Debian/Ubuntu package search pages?

Tags: fedora, package-management

The [Debian](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages)/[Ubuntu package search pages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) are very useful to look up what version of a program is available in what distribution series, how programs are split along multiple packages etc.

For example I want to investigate what version of `g++` is available in current Ubuntu:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=g%2B%2B&searchon=names&suite=maverick&section=all

I directly see that the default version is 4.4.4, also available is 4.5.1. In Natty it is 4.5.1:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=g%2B%2B&searchon=names&suite=natty&section=all

Via http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/g++ you can browse coveniently through the dependencies and directly see which architectures are supported.

You can also search the contents of the packages.

For Fedora I've found

https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb

Searching for g++ returns nothing:

https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/list/*g++*

Ok, perhaps it is split differently:

https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/list/?searchwords=*gcc*

This yields results and it seems that there is only one big `gcc` package which includes `g++`:

https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/gcc

But this is not true. Using `yum search` on a Fedora 14 system yields:

```
  gcc-c++
```

(which includes g++)

Without access to an actual Fedora system, do I really have to somehow expect this and browse down into the package git tree to get the same information? I mean like this:

http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/gitweb/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc.spec;h=683faf0cb3d528bd53fe6a4024fda3e84cc986d0;hb=HEAD

(and then search for '%package' ?)

The https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/gcc shows me that a gcc package is available in Fedora 13 and 14 but it does not show:

- the dependencies
- the actual versions
- the architectures
- sub-packages

Ok, I can see the versions via going to https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/gcc

Thus my question: What is the Fedora equivalent to the Debian/Ubuntu package search pages?

What do you use to look similar information up?

And what about getting this kind of information for other rpm based distros like Cent OS or RHEL?

Comment: Koji is the best option currently, but there is a new web application planned that might improve this: http://blog.linuxgrrl.com/2011/07/29/fedora-package-social-networking/

Comment: The question is 10 years old and mostly outdated. Could someone please add an answer as for current state and perhaps taking into account CentOS Stream 8 and RHEL 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fedora PkgDB does have a search syntax so you could search for builds with /usr/bin/g++ in it by searching for `file:/usr/bin/g++` and click Builds.  Click on the blue (i) for more details.  The GCC package has several sub-packages, as described in the gcc.spec file you showed above, which has added to the confusion.

Comment: Does not work form. Just tried ``file:/usr/bin/g++`` on https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb, but got a 500 Internal Error. Is there an alternative that is more reliable?

Comment: Looks like the Fedora Pkgdb is currently broken.  That's valid syntax, according to its own docs.

Comment: Currently, it just returns 0 packages when using `file:/usr/bin/g++`. And I can't find any documentation on the supported search syntax of packagedb. The only linked documentation is about deploying and configuring a packagedb instance ...

Comment: Surprisingly, a 5 year old answer about a web page is no longer accurate. Sorry about that.

Comment: Currently, that's a dead link.

Answer (score 6):

The Fedora package search application is available at: http://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages

Comment: It's not every useful.  Searching it for "g++" doesn't even come close to returning the package containing g++.

Answer (score 5):

I use http://koji.fedoraproject.org

I hadn't seen PkgDB before, so I can't say much about it.  Koji works well but the only caveat is that it shows packages that have been built and they aren't necessarily in the repository yet.

Comment: Koji is the vat where new packages (even experimental ones, which will never see the light) are brewed. Not your most reliable source...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dnf` to search for stuff. E.g. `dnf list gcc*` lists all packages with name starting `gcc`(be careful with locally resolved globs!), `dnf list /usr/bin/ls` lists the package containing that file, `dnf info gcc` gives (more) details on the package called `gcc`. Check out manual!

Comment: I know `dnf`. But the question really is about a different topic, i.e. searching Fedora package information via online resources. Use case: you don't always have shell access to the right Fedora version but still want to answer certain queries such as: how is the Fedora package called that provides this tool? Is program X packaged at all in Fedora? Since which Fedora version is this package available? etc.