# How to search for official RHEL packages

Tags: rhel

I'd like to know how to do this via the web, something similar to [Debian's official package search page](http://packages.debian.org/).

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/what-is-the-fedora-equivalent-to-the-debian-ubuntu-package-search-pages - at the end I extend the question to RHEL as well

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ensure you have a Red Hat account with an active subscription<sup>(1)</sup> and go to [access.redhat.com/downloads/content/package-browser](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/package-browser), log in with your Red Hat Account, and search the packages.

---

*<sup>(1)</sup> If you don't have a Red Hat account with an active subscription, you have to register for a free developer account at [developers.redhat.com](https://developers.redhat.com/). It's important you register via the `developers.redhat.com` domain as those accounts receive a free developer subscription; accounts registered via the `access.redhat.com` do not and result in an "Active subscription required" message when accessing the package-browser.*

*As of 2023-09-01 there is no way to link an account registered on `access.redhat.com` with the free subscription from `developers.redhat.com`.*

Comment: So, there is no way to do this without having that ID?

Comment: Well if you have a legal copy of RHEL you should have that ID :-/. But thats the most official site youre going to get. You can browse the centos repos, but thats as close as you can get

Comment: Stupid. My client has the license. It would be nice if I could develop software for him without bothering him for these details, after all these package version numbers are hardly top secret?

Comment: @JürgenStrobel If youre going to develop, you'll need to have a box running the OS which you definitely cant do without a license. However CentOS is binary compatable with RHEL. You should be able to develop on it wihout any issues.

Comment: @Patrick: No. I very definitely can develop software on OSX or any other Linux (Unix), for example Debian, and I prefer the luxury of my own and better tools.

Comment: @Patrick - We are kind of in the same spot... Tshepbang and Jürgen. We want to send Red Hat a notice of an updated software package, but we can't find an email address for the maintainers at Red Hat.

Comment: As of Sep 2021 this RedHat page required a PAID subscription to access it :( 

Interesting coincidence that after IBM acquired RedHat, RedHat services are increasingly paid, and decreasingly free :(

For free options to search RPM packages, find those other options contributed by Nemo at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6873/210877

Comment: I just tested. Still works, and is still free.

Comment: After signing up, all I get is: “Active Subscription Required”. I thought I’d sign up for a trial subscription, but it just gives me a full list of all possible subscriptions and I don’t even know which one I need.

Comment: @Chortos-2 I'm not sure what you signed up for, but there's no trial involved in a developer account. I just tried it again, and it still works. I went to developers.redhat.com (the second link in my answer), signed up for an account, confirmed my email address with the email they send, clicked on the first link in my answer, selected "personal account" and entered all the fields, and after submitting, it took me straight to the packages list.

Comment: @phemmer OK, I get it now. Your answer says “Red Hat Account”, so that’s what I signed up for. Step by step: I clicked on your first link. A login form opened. I clicked “Register for a Red Hat account”. In the form, I selected “Personal” and entered all the mandatory fields. After submitting, no email was sent to me, and your first link kept saying “Active Subscription Required”. Just now, I opened your _second_ link and clicked “Log in” there. It automatically logged me in and sent me a verification email. After verifying, _now_ I can open the package list.

Comment: Looking at https://developers.redhat.com/about, the “developer program”, which your second link allows to join, includes a full free Red Hat Enterprise Linux subscription, which is what grants access to the package browser. I think this definitely needs to be featured more prominently in the answer. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

What do you need to find out about packages?

- if you have a RHEL box:

  - use RHN web site
  - use `yum` or `repoquery`
- if not:

  - do an RPM search for CentOS which should be similar, e.g. using [pbone RPM Search](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/2/simple/2) or [rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net/)
  - browse the Red Hat download site for SRPMS, e.g. [5Server RPMs](ftp://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS/)

Comment: Regarding the pbone search, are the results I get for official RHEL packages, or simply packages built for RHEL?

Comment: View the page and see for yourself.  There is no option for RHEL5 or RHEL6, only CentOS.

Comment: Actually, there is, for RHEL 5 and lower.

Comment: Pardon me!  There is!  :-)

Comment: I tried searching for `coreutils` and the links all pointed to a site in Spain that looked to be a Scientific Linux mirror.  So I'm pretty sure they're not official RHEL packages.

Comment: google site:http://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/linux/enterprise/ package_name

Comment: *Sources for RPMS shipped (These are the srpms and metadata for content shipped. More information on how to use these repos is posted at http://wiki.centos.org/Sources)* – https://git.centos.org/project/rpms

Answer (score 2):

Here is the PDF file for RHEL 8:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/pdf/package_manifest/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-8-Package_manifest-en-US.pdf

It contains the package listing for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.

Comment: no versions thought :(

Answer (score 0):

This link can help:

[PDF redhat RHEL 7 Package Manifiest](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/pdf/package_manifest/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Package_Manifest-en-US.pdf)